# Log4j2 automatic reconfiguration when file size exceeds

Tags: log4j2

In log4j2, I wanted to reconfigure automatically when file size exceeds. I have seen the attribute monitorinterval but it is defined for time based triggering policy. But I am looking for size based triggering policy.

Comment: I have never heard anyone ever ask for reconfiguration to take place when a file exceeds a specified size. Are you sure you didn’t mean you want the file to rollover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume that you want to know how to roll over a file when its size exceeds some threshold since reconfiguring automatically when a file exceeds some size is not something I have ever been asked before.

To roll over the file you would use the RollingFileAppender with the SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy. The configuration below will roll over the file once it hits 250 MB.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="MyApp" packages="">
  <Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="logs/app.log"
                 filePattern="logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%i.log">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
      <Policies>
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="250 MB"/>
      </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="error">
      <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: My situation is to create a new log file with new time stamp for each run. With Log4j2 default behaviour, it always creates the current file name with same time stamp. What I am doing is, when file size exceeds I am doing reconfigure so that it will reload all the properties and create new log file with new time stamp. I wanted to check is there any possibility from Log4j2 to reconfigure automatically when file size exceeds.

Comment: So you are using the rolling file appender but you really don't want to use the rolling file feature? This doesn't make sense to me. Don't you get the behavior you want by using the DirectWriteRolloverStrategy and using the file pattern as the name of the file you are writing to? Reconfiguration doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried with DirectWriteRolloverStrategy, even with this log file name created with time stamp for first time, later on the same name will be used for incrementing counter. What I wanted is, when rollover happens, I wanted new log file with current time stamp.

Comment: Did you use %d for the time in the file pattern?

Comment: @rogers: Thanks for your help. %d in DirectWriteRolloverStrategy helped me lot. I was able to generate different logfile for each run with new time stamp.

Thanks again for your help. It is very useful for me.